# PHP form to load specified page

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Have tried to figure out how to write this up but for some reason cannot begin to work out how this needs to work.

Please find below the concept of what i am trying to achieve.

User types in 4 digit pin (Checks on MySQL). Once pin typed and submitted will redirect to the relevant URL according to MySQL.

DB:

```
|--Name----|--PIN---|-----URL--------|
|--Ryan----|--1987--|-3f5df55.php----|
|--Mel-----|--1474--|-34n31ss.php----|
```

Please help as I am completely stuck where to start.

Comment: Show the php code you tried

Comment: this is a bad security model because someone seeing the url in a log could get to anyone's page...you need to rethink it

Comment: *"PHP form to load specified page"* - Your title doesn't match the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Note:

- In order to achieve your goal, we will be using `HTML`, `PHP`, and `mysqli_*` [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).
- What is the name of your table where you have the `Name`, `PIN`, and `URL` columns?
- We can use `header()` to redirect the page to the corresponding URL of the entered PIN.
- Just replace the necessary table name, column name, host name, username, password, and database name (*remember that these are case sensitive*) below

First is we create a form:

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- PHP CODE HERE -->

  <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="number" name="pin" placeholder="4 DIGIT PIN" min="1000" max="9999" required>
    <input type="submit" name="submit-form">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then create a PHP script that will accept the form (*you can put this above your form*):

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST["submit-form"])){

    /* ESTABLISH CONNECTION FIRST TO YOUR DATABASE */
    $con = new mysqli("YourHost", "YourUsername", "YourPassword", "YourDatabase"); /* REPLACE NECESSSARY DATA */

    /* CHECK THE CONNECTION */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
      exit();
    }

    if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT URL FROM table_name WHERE PIN = ?")){ /* CHECK IF THE PREPARED STATEMENT IS TRUE */
      $stmt->bind_param("i",$_POST["pin"]); /* BIND THE PASSED ON ENTERED PIN TO THE QUERY */
      $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE THE QUERY */
      $check = $stmt->num_rows; /* STORE THE NUMBER OF RESULTS */
      if($check > 0){ /* CHECK IF THERE IS FOUND */
        $stmt->bind_result($url); /* BIND THE RESULT TO THIS VARIABLE */
        $stmt->fetch(); /* FETCH THE RESULT */
        header("LOCATION:".$url); /* REDIRECT THE PAGE TO THE CORRESPONDING URL */
      }
      else { /* IF NO PIN NUMBER FOUND IN THE DATABASE */
        echo "Invalid PIN Number";
      }
      $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE THE PREPARED STATEMENT */
    } /* END OF PREPARED STATEMENT */

  } /* END OF ISSET */

?>
```